# Google Analytics -Android Issue

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to track my android application.
My analytics.xml file is pasted below:

```
<!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-36116792-1</string>

<!-- Enable Activity tracking -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<string name="ga_appName">MyRemoteApp</string>
<string name="ga_appVersion">V3</string>

<bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>


<string name="philips.myremote.epg.EPGViewforPhone">TV Guide</string>
```

I am expecting that in Google Analytics dashboard Screen Views should be visible under title "TV Guide" but I am getting "philips.myremote.epg.EPGViewforPhone" instead.How can I resolve this problem or what is wrong in my code?

Comment: I got the same problems. do you find you the solution already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics uses canonical classes names to fetch activity names from resources.

Write in log your activity canonical name:

```
Log.i("TAG", getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

and use this name in resourse as key.

Comment: I did not get you,how can I use this in my analytics.xml to send correct data

Comment: In your Activity onCreate type Log.i("TAG", getClass().getCanonicalName()); and see LogCat. Use printed string in analytics.xml